# How many "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" is allowed in a Facebook App?

Tags: facebook

Is there any limit on how many `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` are allowed to register in a Facebook App ?

We often need to create new websites that allow user to sign in with our App, but I could not find any source about this information.

Comment: Good question. I had 10 running not too long ago.

Comment: Did you ever find out if there is a limit ? We are currently investigating the same

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find for Facebook, but it looks like a maximum of 10 is a common standard:

"up to 10" - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-considerations.htm

"up to 10" - https://developers.nest.com/guides/account-management/multi-redirect

"hard limit of 10" - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/apps/guides/callback-urls

"Up to ten" - https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-safety

Answer (score 1):

From my experience since I asked the question:

Currently we have 27 redirect URLs, and they worked fine. We also never receive any warnings from Facebook regarding this behavior in our Facebook App. We add new URLs often and do clean up unused URLs from time to time.

Still no official document found, but at least this is one data point.